# Gsettings not changing wallpaper

Tags: shell-script, fedora, gnome3, desktop-environment, gsettings

I'm trying to change desktop wallpaper with bash script, the script works on Fedora workstation 27, Ubuntu and Kali but it doesn't work on Fedora KDE 27 and Fedora mate compiz 27. The `picture-uri` is set properly but the wallpaper doesn't change. I'm using the following code to change the wallpaper.

```
DISPLAY=:0 GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri '"file://'$FILE_PATH'"'
DISPLAY=:0 GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options $WALLPAPER_OPTIONS
```

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri` output the correct file path.

```
'file:///home/julekgwa/Pictures/BluePlankton_EN-AU9721339029_1366x768.jpg'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: KDE won't consult GNOME settings to see what wallpaper to show.  you'll have to use something other than `gsettings`.